# 'if statement' removes all lines that don't match the condition, I dont want that

Tags: python, if-statement, multiplication

I'm new to Python and I'm struggling with something fairly basic.

*What I'm trying to do:*

I have a text file consisting of multiple lines. I want the index number [-3] to be multiplied by 2.

However, I only want Python to multiply the index [-3] of every line **if** index number [6] is equal to 1.

If index number [6] of my line is 0, I don't want to multiply the number by 2. I just want the line to remain in the text file, completely unchanged.

*Here's the problem:*

If I use the 'if' statement, it perfectly multiplies the index number [-3] if my in line. Example of a multiplied line where the 6th index is 1, so Python is allowed to multiply by 2:

FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty **1** q_ dw 0 **0.1** 0 flbo || This becomes -->

FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty **1** q_ dw 0 **0.2** 0 flbo

However, if Python sees index number [6] isn't 1, it just skips the line. This is not what I want, because in this way I lose my data. Before I start my script, my text file has 10 lines. The resulting file has 9 lines. So it's lost a line. Example":

FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty **0** q_ dw 0 **8** 0 flbo || This becomes -->

nothing. line is gone.

*My question:*

How can I get Python to 'remember' the lines for which the if statement is false?

I have tried to use the pass function, but the result is exactly the same.

*My current script / solution:*

I have solved the problem in a very ugly way, by multiplying the line where index number [6] = 0 by *1. In this way the number doesnt change. But that's not a clean way of programming, I would like to be more efficient. The code:

```
all_data = []
with open('C:\\directory1', 'r') as file_handler:
    for line in file_handler.readlines():
        if line.strip():
            each_line_data = line.split()
            if each_line_data[6] == '1':
                old_debiet = each_line_data[-3]
                new_debiet = float(old_debiet) * 2
                each_line_data[-3] = str(new_debiet)
                new_each_line_data = ' '.join(each_line_data)
                all_data.append(new_each_line_data)
            if each_line_data[6] == '0':
                old_debiet = each_line_data[-3]
                new_debiet = float(old_debiet) * 1
                each_line_data[-3] = str(new_debiet)
                new_each_line_data = ' '.join(each_line_data)
                all_data.append(new_each_line_data)
                print(new_each_line_data)

with open('C:\\directory2', 'w') as file_handler:
    for item in all_data:
        file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Solution in the comments. It was an indent problem.
Code that works:

```
all_data = []
with open('C:\\file1', 'r') as file_handler:
    for line in file_handler.readlines():
        if line.strip():
            each_line_data = line.split()
            if each_line_data[6] == '1':
                old_debiet = each_line_data[-3]
                new_debiet = float(old_debiet) * 2
                each_line_data[-3] = str(new_debiet)
            new_each_line_data = ' '.join(each_line_data)
            all_data.append(new_each_line_data)
            print(new_each_line_data)

with open('C:\\file2', 'w') as file_handler:
    for item in all_data:
        file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Comment: just as a suggestion, I'd use the if statement only to choose the multiplier, that way you don't have to duplicate all the code

Comment: Can you add a sample of you file including 0 et 1 example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to see what each line does and un-indent whatever needs to be done to every line:

```
all_data = []
with open('C:\\directory1', 'r') as file_handler:
    for line in file_handler.readlines():
        if line.strip():
            each_line_data = line.split()
            if each_line_data[6] == '1':
                old_debiet = each_line_data[-3]
                new_debiet = float(old_debiet) * 2
                each_line_data[-3] = str(new_debiet)
            new_each_line_data = ' '.join(each_line_data)
            all_data.append(new_each_line_data)
            print(new_each_line_data)

with open('C:\\directory2', 'w') as file_handler:
    for item in all_data:
        file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

As you can see, joining the line back and appending now happens outside of the `=='1'` if. This is exactly what you need to do for every line, no matter whether it has 1 or 0, or anything else. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the code like this:

```
all_data = []
with open('C:\\directory1', 'r') as file_handler:
    for line in file_handler.readlines():
        if line.strip():
            each_line_data = line.split()

            if each_line_data[6] == '1':
                multiplier = 2
            elif each_line_data[6] == '0'
                multiplier = 1
            else:
                # I'm not sure what you wish to do in this case
                multiplier = 1

            old_debiet = each_line_data[-3]
            new_debiet = float(old_debiet) * 2
            each_line_data[-3] = str(new_debiet)
            new_each_line_data = ' '.join(each_line_data)
            all_data.append(new_each_line_data)

with open('C:\\directory2', 'w') as file_handler:
    for item in all_data:
        file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `csv` module in the standard library.

You also need to make sure you always record/output the row, regardless of conditions.  As @nathan suggested, it makes sense to conditionally choose the multiplier, then process the row *unconditionally.*

The solution below is *streaming*, in the sense that it doesn't accumulate all data in memory.  Instead, it processes each row and writes it, so that the memory usage is constant (instead of O(N)).

```
import csv
import io

input_contents = """\
FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty 1 q_ dw 0 0.1 0 flbo
FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty 1 q_ dw 0 0.2 0 flbo
FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty 0 q_ dw 0 8.0 0 flbo
"""

with io.StringIO(input_contents) as input_file, io.StringIO() as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=" ")
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=" ")

    for row in reader:
        factor = 2.0 if row[6] == '1' else 1.0
        row[-3] = float(row[-3]) * factor
        writer.writerow(row)

    # Show output for SO purposes
    print(output_file.getvalue())
```

Output is this:

```
FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty 1 q_ dw 0 0.2 0 flbo
FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty 1 q_ dw 0 0.4 0 flbo
FLBO id 'Boundary' st 0 ty 0 q_ dw 0 8.0 0 flbo
```